# mailto: shortcut on windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox, email, mailto

http://www.computerhope.com/tips/tip165.htm

I'm essentially trying to do what is in the link above without having a default mail program set. Put 'mailto:youremail@somewhere.com' in a shortcut on windows and have it to open a mail program of your choice and put that addy in the too field. Something like firefox does would be ideal.

[image: Firefox Example]

What I'm wanting to do with this is to put it in dropbox and have a clickable shortcut to email my teacher when I need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can put something like this in your shortcut:

"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" mailto:youremail@somewhere.com

It'll open the mailto link using firefox, so you should get the firefox dialog options.

Comment: Awesome!! Worked like a charm!!